# Azure Ubuntu 15.04 virtual machine can't change date/time

Tags: date, ubuntu, azure, time, virtual-machine

I'm ruining an Ubuntu 15.04 OS on Azure Virtual Machine. I can't manually change the date of the system by using the "date" command. Here's a sample run:

```
~# date    
Tue Jul  7 00:24:58 HKT 2015

~# date -s "2014-07-04 10:53:59"
Fri Jul  4 10:53:59 HKT 2014

~# date   
Tue Jul  7 00:25:01 HKT 2015
```

I have uninstalled `ntpdate` but it doesn't make a difference. Has anyone experienced this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you can't change the time of a VM which is hosted by an external provider, because the cost of providing an emulated clock is too high and thus it tends to pick up the clock time of the host machine instead.

Comment: So no way possible to change system time on Azure Linux VM? But i could do it with centos vm, just not with ubuntu 15 vm. I thought the problem was somehow unique to ubuntu.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/07/29/manage-timezone-for-applications-on-windows-azure.aspx - if you're trying to set the time by setting the time, you'd be better off managing the timezone instead.